# How to do a hot update for flutter apps?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to know if it is possible to make hot updates which means pushing a new feature to an app the is already released on the play store or the app store.
For example, I have just integrated a new login system for my user base and I want to just push the new code in my existing app. How would I do it?

Answer (score 11):

That's not yet supported.

You can upvote https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14330 to increase priority